# Cannot echo a JS variable to a jQuery plugin coming from wp_localize_script

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, shortcode

**Short version:** I'm able to get a PHP variable into a JS file using wp_localize_script. On JS file i'm able to echo the variable using console.log, but I cannot get it echo into the jQuery plugin's options.

**Long version:**

1. The plugin shortcode.

   ```
   public function slider_shortcode($atts) {

       $data = shortcode_atts ( 
           array(
               'slideshow' => '',
               'responsive' => '',
           ), 
           $atts 
       );

       $slideshow_att = $data['slideshow'];

       // DEBUG -> IT WORKS. I can see $responsive value on the page.
       print_r($data['responsive']);


       ob_start();
       $my_slider( $slideshow=$slideshow_att );    
       $my_slider_content = ob_get_clean();

       wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-public-script', plugins_url( 'assets/js/public.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, TRUE);
       wp_localize_script(
               $this->plugin_slug . '-public-script',
               'myScriptObject',
               $data
           );



       return $my_slider_content;
   }
   ```
2. The OUTPUT JS file.

   ```
   (function ($) {
       "use strict";

       $(window).load(function () {

           var $resp = myScriptObject.responsive;

           // DEBUG -> IT WORKS. I CAN SEE THE SHORTCODE VALUE.
           console.log($resp);

           $('.my-slider').SuperSlider({
               'fullWidth': true,
               'responsive': $resp, // <<-- HERE IS PROBLEM. IT NEVER CHANGES.
               'dimensions': '900,300',
             });
       });
   }(jQuery));
   ```
3. The shortcode

   `[myslider responsive=true]`
4. The value *true* is printed out using `print_r($data['responsive'])` and `console.log($resp)`. But for some reason `responsive: $resp` **do not change!**

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure you've got a boolean value and not a string?

Comment: Whatever value I use there, it will not echo on JS file.

Comment: you say your console statement works, so the var is set. my point was the script is expecting a boolean value, but you are possibly passing it a string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How do I check that?

Comment: @Daniel, if @Milo's point is right using shortcode `[myslider responsive=1]` and in jQuery `var $resp = Boolean(myScriptObject.responsive);` should solve the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that. I tried you suggestion and I'm still getting the value printed out everywhere else, but on the public.js file.

Comment: you misunderstand how this works. you're not going to see the value printed within the js file in place of `$resp`, you're referencing a variable which holds the value. if `console.log($resp)` prints the correct value to the console, then it's working.

Comment: Yeah, I'm misunderstanding something here; console.log($resp) is printing the correct value to the console. But why can't I have it printed within the js file?

Comment: why do you need it printed within the file? the entire point of wp_localize_script is so you don't have to do this. it's not clear why you need this when what you've got works for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot connect the dots. The shortcode is for a slider. I want to use the shortcode parameters to setup the slider. The js file is the slider's jquery plugin's option file. It's the file the initialise the slider. So, are you saying that I don't need that file, right? So, how do I initialise the slider options? I used this plugin as base http://goo.gl/V6CM2i it does use a js file. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: you *do* need the file that initializes the slider, but you don't need to physically write to that file. the fact that you are able to log the variable to the console correctly from that file proves this. if you look at the html page source, you will see a script tag that WordPress has generated which contains your `myScriptObject` localization data. all javascript on the page operates in a global space, so any javascript file on the page has access to that data without it having to be physically embedded within the file.

Comment: Ha ha! I got it! Please put your last comment as answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Daniel, when there are more than 2 parties in a Comment thread, there's no automatic notification, and you need to specifically address the person with an `@`, like: @Milo.  . . . Note, that you can only address one person per comment. . . . If he doesn't post an Answer, feel free to add your own, so this Question doesn't remain *Unanswered*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered using insights from @Milo.